# python re.search return None and Object

Tags: python, regex, django

I have a method in a utils file like this

```
def validate_string(string):
    regex = r"^[a-zA-Z-_áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚÑñ][a-zA-Z0-9-_áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚÑñ\s]*$"
    # return True if re.search(regex, string) else False
    if re.search(regex, string):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

and I use it in a Django class-bassed view to validate some input fields

```
class ClassBassedView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            name = self.request.POST['menu_new_name']
            description = self.request.POST['menu_new_description']
            fields = [[name, "El nombre"], [description, "La descripcion"]]
            re_error = False

            for item in fields:
                if re.search("[!#%&;]", item[0]):
                    re_error = "{0} no puede contener los caracteres #, !, ;, % o &.".format(item[1])
                    break
                elif validate_string(item[0]) is False:
                    print "(%s) (%s)" % (item[0], validate_string(item[0]))
                    re_error = "{0} solo puede contener letras, numeros y guiones medios y bajos. No puede iniciar con"\
                               " numeros.".format(item[1])
                    break
```

Then, by example, when I run this view I send the post values:

```
{'menu_new_name': "Hello", 'menu_new_description': "Éstíló"}
```

I got the print:

```
(Éstíló) (False)
```

but when I run from the shell

```
python manage.py shell
```

I get:

```
>>> from dathLog.utils import validate_string
>>> s = 'Éstíló'
>>> validate_string(s)
True
>>>
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version
'2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) \n[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)]'
```

Is something wrong with my regex??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Python 2.x you should designate your regexes to be unicode if you are using national characters:

```
regex = ur"^[a-zA-Z-_áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚÑñ][a-zA-Z0-9-_áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚÑñ\s]*$"
```

and also use the following format while testing on the shell:

```
s = u'Éstíló'
```

Comment: + Same goes for the console input string.

Comment: at the begining of both files I'm using `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`, does this fix it?

Comment: You should include the `coding` directive too.